# Create Custom view in Android

Tags: android-layout, android

I need to create a Custom view in android which will have dynamic text like price, address  etc. and also an ImageView inside it as shown in the image below. I tried to find google some tutorial for custom view but didn't find something satisfactory to do all these things. I also need to use onClick event on this view. Please guys, some code would be of great help. I'm a novice to android. I read google tutorial to create custom view but couldn't implement this. 
https://lh4.ggpht.com/HmwmRTx3g9ddkHbgvZXpZOB3Am-O9OQARQ2qpxJ16zTDZbG57CmvgxUC75sGFzC3cqrH

Thanks for attention.

Comment: can you please update the link. its dead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **Custom Overlay** for MapView.

You can check example and implement as per your requirement - [Android MapView Balloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

Comment: What I need is that when user clicks on a particular marker on the map, I need to show this component. And when user clicks on this marker, I need to go to the next activity. Can this be done using these overlays?

Comment: @user1559236 Android MapView Ballons is perfect requirement for you... +1 for link

Comment: @user1559236 This is the ready code, but i would suggest you to understand it once so that you can customize it anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayouts. It is very simple to use. FrameLayout can add several views on top of each other. It creates a stack of the views. Just add whatever views you want to inside FrameLayout and use the property setVisibility() to control when to show which view.